# Any system for indexing and relate the contents of external datasources?

Tags: database, indexing, information-retrieval

Does anyone know of a library or project that indexes the contents of different datasources (mainly databases) and allows queries linking data between these sources?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[OGSA-DAI](http://www.ogsadai.org.uk/about/index.php) allows you to run distributed queries by interfacing them via a middleware that uses Web Services as communication protocol.